# On a comment by the mathematician George F. Simmons on stages of proof understanding.

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, soft-question

I came across the quote below on a website. It concerns different stages of proof understanding, and is apparently by George F. Simmons:

> It is a basic principle in the study of mathematics, and one too seldom emphasized, that a proof is not really understood until the stage is reached at which one can grasp it as a whole and see it as a single idea. In achieving this end, much more is necessary than merely following the individual steps in the reasoning. This is only the beginning. A proof should be chewed, swallowed, and digested, and this process of assimilation should not be abandoned until it yields a full comprehension of the overall pattern of thought.

Restricting the scope of my question to concern only proofs in standard textbooks at undergraduate level (i.e. *not* involved research level proofs), I would appreciate some insight from members of the community here on the following open-ended questions:

1. *In your experience of mathematics, what is your conception of that which Simmons refers to when he says that a "proof is not really understood until the stage is reached at which one can grasp it as a whole and see it as a single idea."?*

2. *If question 1 is too "slippery" to answer, then can you say, without answering 1, that you can see proofs as "a single idea"?*

3. *If so, then can you name a proof, roughly at an introductory 1st year undergraduate level, which you feel appropriately exemplifies the content of Simmons' quotation?*

**Context and information about my background.**

I am relatively inexperienced at writing formal mathematical proofs by myself, by which I mean proofs which require a degree of insight, originality, or "tricks". More concretely, my exposure to proof-writing ranges from high-school level proofs which require minimal insight, and I have just started practising this more in self-study of real analysis using *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott (2015). Concerning reading proofs, I have some experience with reading proofs in theoretical statistics and statistical learning theory.

**Rationale.**

The reason why I have asked the above questions is because I found that his specific comment on being able to grasp a proof *"as a whole"* and seeing it as a *"single idea"* is a framing which is new and alien to me; but at the same time, innately appealing to the extent that I would like to know what more experienced mathematicians think about this.

To elaborate a little more on this, I am comfortable with conceiving of the following with reading proofs and writing proofs:

- More granular: Seeing a proof as a series of individual deductive steps (what steps are needed).
- Less granluar: Understanding the motivations of how a proof is constructed *strategically* (what is the broad vision/primary insight/novel idea/trick that motivates the deductive steps). I associate this stage of understanding with being fluent enough with the broad ideas so as to be able to reconstruct, but not recollect verbatim from memory, the proof from first principles.

The Simmon's quotation is also concerning for me. Because it has invited me to re-evaluate whether there exist deficiencies in what I aspire to when I attempt to understand a proof; in that there may be a more abstract, less granular level of understanding that I have previously not conceived of, and which has eluded me:

- Least granular: Seeing the proof as a whole, or as a single idea (???)

On the other hand, what tempers my concern is that this may just be Simmons' way of expressing what people might mean when they say "solid understanding". And that it is an intrinsic way of describing solid understanding, rather than a pragmatic one, e.g. is your understanding of the proof at a level where you can fluently communicate its contents to a peer? If that is the case then perhaps there is less of a cause concern. The last possibility I have in mind is that perhaps he might just be describing a stage of understanding of a proof in the vein of Gestalt psychology, where one can grasp a series of elements as a whole (the pictures).

However, I am unsure about this, which is why the receipt of responses from one's own experiences on this, or even reading suggestions in this area, would be warmly welcome. If this question is not closed for being too open-ended, perhaps it could be added to community wiki (I don't know how to do this), because there are no "correct" answers that can be accepted for this.

Comment: While I do agree with the sentiment of the quote, I think it is silly to expect yourself to reach that standard, especially at your level. This sort of understanding IMO requires several years of practice with proof techniques. For now, focus on being able to come up with proofs yourself. Then, if you are ambitious, try to extract the large scale ideas from the proof. That should suffice.

Comment: As a personal anecdote, it took me around 6 different attempts, spread over the course of 4 years, to study the proof of Stokes's theorem, starting from the standard divergence-curl formulation up to the generalized form with de Rham's theorem. Each time, I got something new out of the proof, and a better appreciation of the result. I still don't feel I've reached the level of the quote.

Comment: @Don Thousand. Thank you for the pragmatic advice. But it seems you describe a general state of mathematical maturity and understanding. Unless there is something I am missing, isn't Simmons referring to a specific instance of understanding a particular proof?

Comment: He is describing an isolated instance, but the kind of comprehension he refers to is more of a reflection of mathematical maturity than any particular proof. I wouldn't sweat over it.

Comment: Oh, another example: I've studied and proved the Jordan Curve Theorem many, many times. I still don't get it.

Comment: I'm in favor of doing examples. Nice anecdote about Hassler Whitney in a book by Keith Kendigcalled Conics; I think he recently published an entire book on Whitney. Anyway, Kendig told Whitney a theorem, Whitney said he never heard of it, then said "Let's see if I can disprove it"  and gave a string of examples, gradually closer to the edge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

previews  [Conics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Conics/GLwgDjdXApUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)  and [Whitney Biography](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Never_a_Dull_Moment/aaVyDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)

turns out I have this as a jpeg. About halfway down he talks about Whitney and Bezout's theorem. In the last paragraph on this page, he says

> I'd known about that result for at least two years, and I realized
> that in 15 or 20 minutes, he'd gained a deeper appreciation of it than
> I'd ever had.

[image]

half the page, better visibility, except that the search words used are highlighted:

[image]

Comment: +1. Thank you for this. I can relate to this (although not at this level of sophistication), and I'm sure others can also. I've definitely found that when a definition or theorem is too terse or abstract, looking at judiciously chosen examples which succeed and fail to meet the criteria helps enormously. Which does make me wonder whether there is something about the role similarity and difference has to play in the process of understanding mathematical abstractions. This has definitely supplied some insight for me on this, as well as a moment of hilarity imagining the situation with H.W.